# String literals in c

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I'm having a bit of trouble with `C` and character arrays. I tried to search on SO but I didn't really see anything that could help me or I was not looking for the right thing.

I've this function:

```
char* readFile(char* file_path)
{
  FILE* fp = fopen(file_path, "r");
  size_t buffer = 4096;
  char ch;
  int index = 0;
  char* line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer);
  while( (ch = (char)fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
  {
      line[index] = ch;
      ++index;
      if(index == buffer -1)
      {
          buffer = buffer * 2;
          line = realloc(line, buffer);
      }
  }
  line = realloc(line, (sizeof(char) * index));
  line[index] = '\0';
  fclose(fp);
  return line;
}
```

Now, when I use this function in my code and try to free the reference, it causes a crash so I think I'm leaking memory somewhere.

```
char* data;

data = readFile("....");
free(data) <-- this line causes a crash!
```

I know if I didn't `malloc` inside the function the memory would go out of scope so that's a no go but using the current function as is, I get a crash. What I'm doing wrong?

**edit**
After doing this read file

after the above readFile function I go into this function

```
GLuint getShaderProgram(const char* vshad, const char* fshad)
{
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vshad, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR VERTEX COMPILATION_FAILED %s\n",infoLog);
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    GLuint fragmentShader  = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fshad, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR FRAGMENT COMPILATION_FAILED %s\n",infoLog);
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR SHADER PROGRAM COMPILATION_FAILED %s\n",infoLog);
        SDL_Quit();
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    return shaderProgram;
}
```

so the full code path is like this

```
char* vv = readFile("vshad.vs");
char* ff = readFile("fshad.fs");

sp = getShaderProgram(vv, ff);

free(vv);
free(ff);
```

I get crashes at the free(..), removing those and the program runs fine but I feel it's a memory leak.

Comment: `ch` should be `int`, not `char`, because that's the return value of `fgets` which allows it to distinguish between regular input and `EOF`. When you shrink your string, you should allocate `index + 1` bytes, the additional byte is for the null terminator.

Comment: Your final `realloc()` size is too small by one... you need `index + 1` bytes, so that `line[index]` is still in bounds for the null char.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` equals `1` by definition. All those cast are useless and even more the one for `fgets()` hides a serious programming bug as *M Oehm* points out in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110672/strings-literals-in-c#comment52115104_32110672

Comment: A crash on `free` may occur if internal control data is overwritten. What do you do between `readFile` and ´free`? Have you considered running the program in a memory-checker such as Valgrind?

Comment: @MOehm thanks i'll make those changes. I use that readFile function to load a glsl shader. I'll update the question with more code.

Comment: Rather than `int index = 0;`, should use `size_t index = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insufficient memory is allocated for the array. You have just allocate memory for the character array but not for the terminating `\0` character. This leads to **undefined behavior**.

Please change the following line:

```
line = realloc(line, (sizeof(char) * index));
```

to

```
line = realloc(line, (sizeof(char) * (index+1)));
```

Also, change the datatype of `ch` to int from `char`since the return type of `fgetc()` is `int` (not `char`). It is recommended to assign the returned values to an integer type variable.

When you read the value into a `char` instead of an `int`:

1. If char is `unsigned`, then you get an infinite loop as we never get `EOF`.
2. If char is `signed`, then `0xFF` (i.e `ÿ` is accepted as EOF) is taken into account as `EOF` producing wrong results.

> Also, check whether the functions worked as intended or not:

- Check file opening was successful or not.
      FILE* fp = fopen(file_path, "r");
      if(fp != NULL){
        //Do Stuff
      }
- Check whether memory was allocated or not

  ```
  char* tmpLine = realloc(line, (sizeof(char) * (index+1)));
  if (tmpLine != NULL)
  {
    line = tmp;
    line[index] = '\0';
  }
  else
  {
    //Handle insufficient memory
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

In C it is important to check return values from functions that have return values. In your case you use realloc but don't bother to check the return value.

```
char* tmp = realloc(line, newbuffersize);
if (tmp != NULL)
{
  line = tmp;
}
else
{
  abort();
}
```

You should check if the file was opened properly, if it fails and you start using the null pointer in your calls you will get funny behavior.

Once leaving your while loop you downsize the buffer with a new realloc. That is fine but you need to add room for the ending \0 :

```
char* tmp = realloc(line, index + 1);
if (tmp != NULL)
{
  line = tmp;
  line[index] = '\0';
}
```

Generally speaking it is a bit ineffective to allocate as you do it, it would be more effective if first you check the size of the file (e.g. see fseek to the end and then do ftell then fseek to start) and then allocate a buffer with the same size (+1) before reading - if you not for some reason have draconian memory constraints or a massive big file.

Answer (score 1):

change `line = realloc(line, (sizeof(char) * index));` to

```
line = realloc(line, (sizeof(char) * (index+1)));
```

You are trying to realloc `line` to `index` size and next statement you are trying to store '\0' character in `line[index]` which is undefined behavior.